# How to retrieve subdocuments references in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

**Data structure**

```
"classrooms" : [
    {
        id : ObjectId("class1")
        "students" : [
            ObjectId("student1")
        ],
    },
    {
        id : ObjectId("class2")
        "students" : [
        ]
    }
],
"students" : [
    {
       "id" : ObjectId("student1"),
       "firstname" : "Ciljan",
       "age" : NumberInt(23)
    },
    {
       "id" : ObjectId("student2"),
       "firstname" : "John",
       "age" : NumberInt(19)
    }
]
```

**The need**

I have to provide a document where there are classrooms and students.
Students could be assigned to a specific classroom, but not always, so a student could keep free.
With the previous data structure, I have the subdocument "**students**" that provides the list of all the available students both assigned and not assigned. I can assign a student to a classroom storing the student id in the classrooms students array.

**Problem**

How can I retrieve these data in order to have for each classroom all the records about their assigned students?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like `Classroom.find({}).populate('students')`? That'll return an array of Classrooms with the student fields populated.

Comment: Maybe, but this "populate" function doesn't exist for the MongoDB Node.js Native Driver. Maybe is this command for Mongoose?

Comment: the mongoose module has 'populate' already built in: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate
In looking at your snippet, it looks like classrooms and students are part of a larger Schema, in which case the deep-populate plugin is what you need: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-deep-populate

Once you register the plugin with the schema, the call is LargerSchema.find({}).deepPopulate('classrooms classrooms.students')

Comment: Thank you very much, although I have to use just **MongoDB Node.js Native Driver** and not Mongoose. The module that you link is always related to a Mongoose Schema that for my logic implementation I can't use. Maybe I have to do it myself.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case, no, there isn't a way, but there have been a few solutions offered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19678259/nodejs-mongodb-how-to-query-ref-fields